# The second frame around the table cells (only in Chrome), how to get rid?

Tags: html, css

I create a table using the `display: table;` property. Table cells have their own 5px border and `border-radius` property. In the browser, chrome (only) around the cell borders, another 1px frame appears (which disappears when scaling and is visible only at the places where the cell borders are rounded)

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: #514B48;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 90px;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 5px solid #514B48;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1e1c20;
    color: #fff;
    width: 90px;
    min-width: 90px;
    line-height: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <ul class="table-row">
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="table-row">
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Screenshot:[Line around the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYAMl.png)

**UPDATE**
One solution:

```css
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    /*Delete the border, transfer to :before*/
    max-width: 600px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1e1c20;
    color: #fff;
    width: 90px;
    min-width: 90px;
    line-height: 90px; /*Change*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 21px;
    -moz-border-radius: 21px;
    border-radius: 21px; /*Change*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative; /*Add*/
}

/* Fix Chrome bug */
.table-cell:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid #514B48;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Partially solves the problem property `outline: 4px solid #514B48;`, but for elements that are located at the edges of the table, these strange lines remain on the fillets.

Comment: The color of this phantom line changes with the background color `.table-cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like a specific bug in Chrome.
You can hide the gap using pseudo-element `:before`.

First add `position: relative` to table cell element:

```
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 5px solid #514B48;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1e1c20;
    color: #fff;
    width: 90px;
    min-width: 90px;
    line-height: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now, it'll be reference for absolutely positioned elements inside it.
Then, you add the `:before` pseudo-element to cover the borders gap:

```
.table-cell:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    top: -6px;
    color: #514B48;
    border: 6px solid;
}
```

Comment: The pseudo-element did not cover these lines, they are still visible

Comment: yes, it works now, thanks. But based on your previous answer, I already solved this problem, I will describe the solution in updating the question. (Although your solution may be better)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

It can help you with alternate way.

```css
        .table {
        display: table;
        margin: 50px auto;
        background: #514B48;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .table-row {
        display: table-row;
        height: 90px;
    }
    
    .table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
    
    }
    .table-cell p{
        border: 5px solid #514B48;
        text-align: center;
        background: #1e1c20;
        color: #fff;
        width: 90px;
        min-width: 90px;
        line-height: 80px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:0;
     
    }
```

```html
    <div class="table">
            <ul class="table-row">
                <li class="table-cell"><p>1</p></li>
                <li class="table-cell"><p>1</p></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="table-row">
                <li class="table-cell"><p>1</p></li>
                <li class="table-cell"><p>1</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I would rather not change the HTML structure, but the alternative is working, thanks